# Algorithm for shortest distance from a point to an elliptic arc

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, 2d

I am trying to find a general method for calculating the shortest distance between an arbitrary point and an arc, where the arc is a 90 degree portion of an ellipse's boundary, and the ellipse's axes are both aligned to the Cartesian axes. I'm working in 2D, so both the point and the ellipse are coplanar. If the point is in the same quadrant as the arc, relative to the centre of the ellipse, then I believe that the problem is the same as calculating the distance from a point to anywhere on the whole ellipse's boundary, for which there are fairly straightforward methods (e.g. http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid.pdf).

In the diagram, if the point is to the left of x1 or to the right of x2 or below y1, then the problem is straight forward.

However, I can't figure out what to do if the point P is as shown in the diagram.

[image: Click here for diagram]

Answer (score 3):

I usually use for ellipses this:

1. **sample the arc by `N` points**

   for `90` degree chunk use `N>=8` so yu do not miss something
2. **find the closest point**
3. **sample arc around that point by `N` points**

   cover area from previous to next point
4. **recursively loop to #2**

   each iteration/recursion increase accuracy. Stop if hit a desired precision range (sampled area is small enough) or variable precision limit (to avoid underflows of **FPU**).

[image: example]

**[Notes]**

This works for any elliptic arc not just axis aligned.

**[Edit1] C++ example**

```
double x0,y0,rx,ry,a0,a1;   // elliptic arc center,semi-axises,start/end angles CW
void ellarc_closest_point(double &x_out,double &y_out,double x_in,double y_in)
    {
    int e,i;
    double ll,l,aa,a,da,x,y,b0,b1;
    while (a0>=a1) a0-=pi2;                 // just make sure a0<a1
    b0=a0; b1=a1; da=(b1-b0)/25.0;          // 25 sample points in first iteration
    ll=-1; aa=a0;                           // no best solution yet
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)                       // recursions more means more accurate result
        {
        // sample arc a=<b0,b1> with step da
        for (e=1,a=b0;e;a+=da)
            {
            if (a>=b1) { a=b1; e=0; }
            // elliptic arc sampled point
            x=x0+rx*cos(a);
            y=y0-ry*sin(a);                 // mine y axis is in reverse order therefore -
            // distance^2 to x_in,y_in
            x-=x_in; x*=x;
            y-=y_in; y*=y; l=x+y;
            // remember best solution
            if ((ll<0.0)||(ll>l)) { aa=a; ll=l; }
            }
        // use just area near found solution aa
        b0=aa-da; if (b0<a0) b0=a0;
        b1=aa+da; if (b1>a1) b1=a1;
        // 10 points per area stop if too small area already
        da=0.1*(b1-b0); if (da<1e-6) break;
        }
    x_out=x0+rx*cos(aa);
    y_out=y0-ry*sin(aa);    // mine y axis is in reverse order therefore -
    }
```

And visual output:

[image: ellarc closest point test]

Comment: Thanks - I am working on an analytical solution at the moment, and had planned to compare it with this sort of 'bisection' approach if I get time.

Comment: @RobB analytical solution and ellipse/elliptic arcs does not go along in most cases. The best you can usually do is just some approximation with questionable error for different eccentricities ...

Comment: That's not the case - the pdf I linked gives an analytical approach  (albeit with a root finding approximation thrown in the mix). It's this that I hope to compare with the bisection approach, given enough time :)

Comment: @RobB from what I quick read it is approximation ... Yes you got analytical formulas but the final solution is numerical approximation anyway. With may be a bit better complexity but the precision will be a bit worse (or the same) then this due to floating rounding errors. Similar to numerical integration paradox (the more advanced method you use the worse is the error if you are near FPU precision barriers).

Comment: @RobB added C++ example

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Hopefully I'll get some time this weekend to play with it :)

Answer (score -1):

So the whole arc thing is a red herring. It's a linear scale back to a unit circle. So you only need to find the shortest distance from a point to the unit circle. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103453/closest-point-to-a-unit-circle-from-a-point-inside-it) Then just undo the scale and measure the distance.

**[Edit by Spektre] This is clearly wrong!**

if you find closest point to a circle (in scaled space) that does not mean that this point after rescaling back (to ellipse space) will still be the closest !!! See example:

[image: example]

Comment: Firstly, we're talking about an ellipse, not necessarily a circle. Secondly, "the whole arc thing" is not a red herring - it's critical. Look at point P in the picture: The closest point on the ellipse is _not_ on the arc.

Comment: My point is that an ellipse is just a circle, scaled, linear. Consider a unit circle sqrt(x^2+y^2)=1. Now instead of x use x/2. sqrt((x/2)^2+y^2)=1. You have an ellipse. If you then do the same transform on a point (x/2) you will get the same closest point.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but, irrespective of whether you deal with the ellipse as a transformed circle or as an actual ellipse, you still have the problem that the closest distance from point P to the circle/ellipse is _not_  on the arc.

Comment: @starmole if you find closest point to a circle (in scaled space) that does not mean that this point after rescaling back (to ellipse space) will still be the closest !!!

Comment: This answer really is completely wrong, and it'd be a great idea to delete it, even after all these years. By definition, the closest projection of a point onto a circle lies on a line that goes through the circle's center, something which is _only_ true for circles, not for ellipses. In fact, because distances between points are not invariant under non-uniform scaling, we don't even need to know what shapes we're dealing to know this answer can never work: scaling does not preserve distances, so distance identities in any coordinate system _do not hold_ after scaling that coordinate system.